# Could the use of von Neumann probes by some precursor be a possible solution to the Great Filter?

Tags: science-based, technology, science-fiction, civilization

I was thinking about including von Neumann probes as the Great Filter in my setting where humanity discovers that there are planets all over the place that have been turned into hollow bodies, eventually coming to the conclusion that there was some unknown precursor civilisation that unleashed true self-replicating von Neumann probes onto the galaxy. Whether it was an act of total war or a vast automated mining program that went terribly wrong, it stripped away many resource-rich planets and asteroids and probably ended countless civilisations that were developing on their home planet.

Assuming that the civilisations that do end up leaving the surface of their planet are geared towards the acquisition of resources at nearly any cost (sounds familiar :D), it may not be entirely unplausible to think that occasionally a civilisation rises and inevitably unleashes von Neumann probes which goes wrong and causes their demise and essentially "sterilises" the galaxy. After all, there's nothing stopping this from happening many times over (except the rate of planet formation and evolution of life on planets, I guess).

Is my reasoning somewhat plausible within a sci-fi setting (or maybe in real life too) or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I feel this question is too open ended.

Comment: Oh, maybe I should come back once I have a better way of saying what I want to say then :)

Comment: A "sterilized" galaxy is one where you don't exist to ask this question.  A Great Filter that states that humans shouldn't exist is not logically sound.

Comment: A couple of points.  1.  An asteroid might be mined into a hollow shell, but a planet cannot be hollowed out through mining, it will collapse without structural support for the crust.  2.  Matter cannot be arbitrarily destroyed, unless it has been converted into energy the same mass will still exist and should be discoverable.

Comment: Are you assuming the von Neumann probes "go rogue" with respect to the goals of the aliens that created them? Do the aliens not have the technology to equip the probes with mind uploads or other form of intelligent A.I. that could be trusted to have the same goals as the aliens themselves, to prevent the probes from just mindlessly devouring everything in order to replicate? Related to this, are you assuming the aliens themselves are biological, that the reins of their civilization haven't been handed over to A.I. of some kind?

Comment: @Hypnosifl I was thinking the opposite, that they should ditch the AI altogether and make the probes too *simple* to rebel. After all, they don't have to be clever to solve problems, because they have that ultimate of problem-solving tools, quantity.

Comment: @Cadence - If they're simple, then that might imply that whatever failsafes prevent them from just replicating endlessly until they eat whole planets would be simple too, and that it'd be easier for some replication error or accident to disable them without disabling the machines' ability to replicate. Whereas a fleet piloted by mind uploads wouldn't seem any more likely to rebel than a fleet piloted by actual biological colonists, assuming the uploads were accurate simulations. And if an individual or faction went rogue, a larger faction might see what was going on and act to stop them.

Comment: In addition to the question of where the mass of the planets went to (which, if not collapsed, would be pulled inevitably towards the body they were spinning around). Do you find the mining efforts result somewhere? Like instead of the civilization that started it all had their planets hollowed out, you would find super massive black holes or bloody big suns or something from all the stuff the hauled back to the civilization and the mass collapsed into a star/black hole?

Comment: This is already a theory. There is a sub-type of Von Neumann probes called "berserkers" which activate when they sense life. The idea is to send one to a planet and if it finds life it self-replicates and goes on to exterminate the life. Berserker probes might also be left as guards and activate if living beings approach them, so starting space exploration might actually be what destroys a planet when they go by a berserker probe. It's entirely possible for these to be "berserkers" by *accident* - malfunctioning normal probes, for example.

Comment: 1. @cowlinator I was thinking that this happened hundreds of millions of years ago and it pretty much missed the solar system 2. The matter has probably been converted into more von Neumann probes and some heat and light energy 3. That is entirely true, but I was thinking from the POV of humanity who have just come up with this theory and have no idea what these precursors were 4. I was thinking along those lines, maybe the line spectra of said stars would be the biggest giveaway due to their increased rare earth metals content.

Answer (score 6):

The issue with this as a great filter is that the Von Neumann Probes wouldn’t just disappear. They might kill everything in the galaxy, but then where would they stop? If they’re already so rogue that they’ve annihilated their makers then nothing stops them from going full Paperclip Optimiser and turning the whole galaxy into more Von Neumanns, thus permanently forestalling the evolution of any further civilisations.

If your probes (for whatever reason) object to organic life but don’t want to make more of themselves then you’ve just reinvented the ‘evil machine race’ Trope, where an alien race of highly advanced machines periodically wipes out life. This isn’t really a great filter, because the race in question will presumably be so much more advanced that their victims have no hope of averting their doom.

Even if (for some bizzare reason) these probes stop making more of themselves and then just shut off, they’ll still hang about and provide ample evidence (and a technological boost) to any race that might arise that’s capable of hitting the filter, meaning it will only filter out one race and then be effectively useless.

The only way this works as a filter is if the probes kill their makers then decide to leave their home galaxy. Which is an odd thing to happen every time this occurs. Perhaps some extragalactic civilisation of Von-Neumanns sends an invite every time a new probe race is detected. Who knows.

Of course, A whole bunch of potential stories exist around these themes (Revelation Space, Mass Effect 3 and Star Trek: Picard are three examples off the top of my head), but it’s critical that you remember that the old Von neumanns wont simply disappear. They have to go somewhere.

Which is true of everything eventually, I guess.